Blazor WASM Unsupported URL scheme
I'm trying to migrate a Blazor WASM hosted project from .net core 3.1 to .net6. Everything is building but when I run the project I get the following error in the console:

fail: Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.DevToolsProxy[0] sending error
response for id: msg-9AA300DED0B65611423B36B5F93D3AF1:::1035 ->
[Result: IsOk: False, IsErr: True, Value: , Error: { "code": -32602 ,
"message": "Unsupported URL scheme" } ]. I must be missing something
along the way.

I must be missing something along the way.Here are some configurations. I don't have any idea where to search and what is the reason.
public static IApplicationBuilder UseEndpoints(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    => app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
    });

public static WebAssemblyHostBuilder AddRootComponents(this WebAssemblyHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
    builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
    return builder;
}

<body>
    <div id="app">
    </div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <Login />
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <CascadingAuthenticationState>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotFound404 />
            </LayoutView>
        </CascadingAuthenticationState>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

